# Issues with payment API using CURL to charge a card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, payment-processing, balanced-payments

In my rails app I am using [balanced payments api](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/#charge-a-credit-card) for credit card transactions. According to the documentation after I collect the info I must run these curl commands. However, I cant figure out what's what. So I can't really use it because I don't know what variables to replace and how to even get them. This is a snippet of their documentation.

Let's charge the card:

First, let's create an account to associate the card token with:

```
curl https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP6NFmfjuy4Os0LSSywJbmk0/accounts \
     -u df6000d8f2ec11e294cf026ba7cd33d0: \
     -d "card_uri=/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP6NFmfjuy4Os0LSSywJbmk0/cards/CCwpuGSqIjnOxUoUrSE4IdV"
```

Associate the token with an account:

```
curl https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP6NFmfjuy4Os0LSSywJbmk0/accounts/AC6VSiS3WD7G1z1BjrMIL4Kk \
     -u df6000d8f2ec11e294cf026ba7cd33d0: \
     -X PUT \
     -d "card_uri=/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP6NFmfjuy4Os0LSSywJbmk0/cards/CC6XpIuz7jymGcPIkCREtx2K"
```

Debit the account:

```
curl https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP6NFmfjuy4Os0LSSywJbmk0/accounts/ACwPcWVArKDYEdOJ8bRHg9w/debits \
     -u df6000d8f2ec11e294cf026ba7cd33d0: \
     -d "amount=1000"
```

So I can understand that `/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP6NFmfjuy4Os0LSSywJbmk0` is my test marketplace URI but what are these other values?

`df6000d8f2ec11e294cf026ba7cd33d0`

`CCwpuGSqIjnOxUoUrSE4IdV`

`AC6VSiS3WD7G1z1BjrMIL4Kk`

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using the balanced ruby client?

https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby

https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api.html?language=ruby

Also, I believe they have an example marketplace Rails app:
https://github.com/balanced/rentmybikes-rails

Comment: Great answer! Let me check those out.